# Partition by time-interval

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, window-functions

I am looking for the best way to run a window function over a partition by  datetime value. However, rather than partition by exact time I want partition by datetimes that are for example within 15 minutes of each other.

Here is a little piece of my table.

```
CREATE TABLE my_table(ID VARCHAR(5), in_time DATETIME)

INSERT INTO my_table (ID, in_time) VALUES
('4844', '2017-04-06 10:15:00.000'),
('5221', '2017-11-24 11:18:00.000'),
('5221', '2017-11-24 11:18:00.000'),
('5221', '2017-11-25 14:23:00.000'),
('8486', '2017-10-10 15:30:00.000'),
('8486', '2017-10-10 15:32:00.000'),
('8486', '2017-10-10 15:46:00.000'), -- new row after updating question
('8486', '2017-10-10 16:00:00.000') -- new row after updating question
```

Here is the query I am using now:

```
SELECT *, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID, in_time ORDER BY ID, in_time) AS filter_row
FROM my_table
```

Which as expected gives me this:

```
ID      in_time                     filter_row
4844    2017-04-06 10:15:00.000     1
5221    2017-11-24 11:18:00.000     1
5221    2017-11-24 11:18:00.000     2
5221    2017-11-25 14:23:00.000     1
8486    2017-10-10 15:30:00.000     1
8486    2017-10-10 15:32:00.000     1
8486    2017-10-10 15:46:00.000     1
8486    2017-10-10 16:00:00.000     1
```

What I would like to achieve is this:

```
ID      in_time                     filter_row
4844    2017-04-06 10:15:00.000     1
5221    2017-11-24 11:18:00.000     1
5221    2017-11-24 11:18:00.000     2
5221    2017-11-25 14:23:00.000     1
8486    2017-10-10 15:30:00.000     1
8486    2017-10-10 15:32:00.000     2 -- < notice the 2 here
8486    2017-10-10 15:46:00.000     3 -- < notice the 3 here
8486    2017-10-10 16:00:00.000     4 -- < notice the 4 here
```

As you see above the rows with `ID = 8486` should be partitioned together, as it is only 2, 14, and 14  minutes between their respective `in_time` and the `in_time` on the row above. How to do this efficiently?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following example provides the desired results by calculating an interval start time based on the specified interval in minutes and partitioning by that value.

```
DECLARE @IntervalMinutes int = 15;
SELECT *, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
          PARTITION BY ID
        , (DATEADD(minute, (DATEDIFF(minute, '', in_time)/@IntervalMinutes)*@IntervalMinutes, '')
        )
        ORDER BY ID, in_time) AS filter_row
FROM my_table;
```

**EDIT:**

The above code calculates fixed-length intervals. Your updated question can be solved by identifying islands by `ID` that exceed the desired interval. The method below uses `NOT EXISTS` along with `CROSS APPLY` to identify these islands and determine the interval start and end time of each island.

```
DECLARE @IntervalMinutes int = 15;
WITH
    start_intervals AS (
        SELECT DISTINCT
              ID
            , in_time
        FROM dbo.my_table AS a
        WHERE NOT EXISTS(
            SELECT 1
            FROM dbo.my_table AS b
            WHERE
                b.ID = a.ID
                AND b.in_time < a.in_time
                AND b.in_time > DATEADD(minute, -@IntervalMinutes, a.in_time)
            )
        )
    , end_intervals AS (
        SELECT
              ID
            , in_time
        FROM dbo.my_table AS a
        WHERE NOT EXISTS(
            SELECT 1
            FROM dbo.my_table AS b
            WHERE
                b.ID = a.ID
                AND b.in_time > a.in_time
                AND b.in_time < DATEADD(minute, @IntervalMinutes, a.in_time)
            )
    )
    , intervals AS (
        SELECT
              ID
            , start_intervals.in_time AS start_interval
            , end_intervals.in_time AS end_interval
        FROM start_intervals
        CROSS APPLY(
            SELECT TOP(1) in_time
            FROM end_intervals 
            WHERE
                end_intervals.ID = start_intervals.ID
                AND end_intervals.in_time >= start_intervals.in_time
            ) AS end_intervals
        )
SELECT 
      my_table.ID
    , my_table.in_time
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY my_table.ID, intervals.start_interval ORDER BY(intervals.start_interval)) AS filter_row
FROM dbo.my_table
JOIN intervals ON my_table.in_time BETWEEN intervals.start_interval AND intervals.end_interval
```

Comment: Neat trick! =D  I'd just add this cool trick is always sticking the times to the "lower end of a time partition", meaning `2017-11-24 11:29:59.999` will be converted to `2017-11-24 11:15:00.000` for example.

Comment: It's obviously not an answer for the condition *I want partition by datetimes that are for example within 15 minutes of each other.* See [DbFiddle.](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d067381c86a258d5b1600fd25beae38d)

Comment: @kiln, agreed if one interprets the question literally. My assumption is that fixed non-overlapping intervals are desired.

Comment: I always interpret questions literally. If it's possible, of course.

Comment: I think I accepted this answer a bit too quick. If I understand your solution correctly, it partitions the dates if they are within the same fixed set of 15-minute intervals? ie. 00:00-00:14, 00:15-00:29, etc.

Comment: @KarlAnka, this code groups and counts rows by starting intervals like '00:00:00', '00:15:00', '00:30:00', etc. Do you want to instead count records more than once for overlapping intervals, such as in the case of many records for the same ID all one minute apart, returning a count of 30 for each minute? Add sample data and expected results and I'll improve my answer to address your needs.